# Guillemin-Pollack: application of the Transversality Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

I'm working on two exercises from Guillemin-Pollack which have the same flavor:

> (General Position Lemma) Let $X$ and $Y$ be submanifolds of $\mathbb R^N$. Show that for almost
>   every $a\in \mathbb R^N$, the translate $X+a$ intersects $Y$
>   transversally.

---

> Suppose that $X$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$. Show that almost every vector space $V$ of any fixed dimension $l$ in $\mathbb R^N$ intersects $X$ transversally. [HINT: The set $S\subset  (\mathbb R^N)^l$ consisting of all linearly independent $l$-tuples if vectors in $\mathbb R^N$ is open in $\mathbb R^{Nl}$, and the map $\mathbb R^l\times S\rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ defined by $[(t_1,\dots,t_l),v_1,\dots,v_l]\mapsto t_1v_1+\dots t_lv_l$ is a submersion.]

---

In both cases, I believe I need to apply the following version of the Transversality Theorem (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1297610/500094) answer):

> **Theorem**: Suppose that $F:X\times S\to Y$ is a smooth map of manifolds and $Z$ is a submanifold of $Y$, all manifolds *without boundary*. If $F$ is transverse to $Z$ then for almost every $s\in S$ the map $f_s : x\mapsto F(x,s)$ is transverse to $Z$.

I have the same problem in both exercises.

- In the first exercise, the theorem guarantees that for almost every $a\in \mathbb R^N$, the map $f_a: X\rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ given by $x\mapsto x+a$ is transversal to $Y$. Note that the image of this map is $X+a$. *I need to show that the image is transversal to $Y$. How does it follow?*
- In the second exercise, the theorem guarantees that for almost every $v=(v_1,\dots,v_l)\in S$, the map $f_v: \mathbb R^l\rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ given by $(t_1,\dots,t_l)\mapsto t_1v_1+\dots+t_lv_l$ is transversal to $X$. Note that the image of this map is an $l$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^N$. *I need to show that the image is transversal to $X$. How does it follow?*

Comment: The second one is false, as stated. You need an *affine* $l$-dimensional subspace, not a vector subspace. Can you see why? By the way, you can find a list of errata in Guillemin and Pollack [here](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/Guillemin_Pollack_errata.pdf).

Comment: @TedShifrin  For the points $v_i$'s they may not have linear combination satisfies $0$.

About affine spaces, how to prove second question?

Comment: I have shown this is a submersion but I am having problem with showing the intersection is transversal, intuitively it is good but formally I cannot write.

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale Of course, $0$ is in the span of any vectors. So a *linear* subspace cannot be transverse to $X$ if $0\in X$ and dimensions are too small. For the second, a submersion is transverse to any submanifold!

Answer (score 2):

Let $i_1 : M_1 \to X$ and $i_2 : M_2 \to X$ be embeddings. The following statements are equivalent:

- $i_1$ and $i_2$ are transverse,
- $i_1$ and $M_2$ are transverse,
- $i_2$ and $M_1$ are transverse,
- $M_1$ and $M_2$ are transverse.

This follows from the fact that for an embedding $f : M \to X$, $f_*(T_pM) = T_{f(p)}(f(M))$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what are $i_1$ and $i_2$ in the context of my question and also what the transversality of two maps means.

Comment: In your first example, you've shown that the embedding $f_a$ is transversal to the submanifold $Y$ (this is the case of the second dot point I listed), and you want to conclude that the image of $f_a$ is transversal to $Y$ (this is the fourth dot point I listed). For transversality of two maps, the definition can be found [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transversal+maps).